# How do I create an array of form fields?

Tags: drupal, forms

I'm writing a custom module and I am trying to create an array of form fields, but it doesn't seem it is what I am doing.

Here's the code I'm trying to use:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
  $form['contact'][$i]['value'] = array(
     '#type' => 'textfield',
     '#title' => 'Contact Name',
     '#size' => 50,
  );
}
```

Doing this, I was expecting the form to print the field as:

```
<input type="text" value="" size="50" name="contact[0][value]" />
<input type="text" value="" size="50" name="contact[1][value]" />
<input type="text" value="" size="50" name="contact[2][value]" />
```

Instead, it outputs:

```
<input type="text" value="" size="50" name="0" />
<input type="text" value="" size="50" name="1" />
<input type="text" value="" size="50" name="2" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, all you need is to do this, but keep in mind this also changes how the values get returned in your form submit functions (you'll get a nested array rather than separate values in $form_state['values']).

```
$form['contact']['#tree'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: Thanks!  Didn't know that was even an option

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided is exactly what i needed. This is my code, which will probably help future developers.

```
$form['results']['subject'] = array(
    '#tree' => TRUE
);

foreach($subjectList as $subject) {
    $form['results']['subject'][$subject->id] = array(
        '#type'      => 'textfield',
        '#title'     => $subject->name, 
        '#maxlength' => 3, 
        '#required'  => TRUE,
    );
}
```